# how to pass $index to array value?

Tags: php, angularjs

```
$Product = array("aaa","bbb","ccc");
$suppliername = array("S0001","S0002","S0001");
$vals = array_count_values($suppliername);
print_r($suppliername);
print_r($vals);

foreach($Product as $index => $value)
{   
    if($vals[$index]>1)
    {
        echo $suppliername[$index]."+++"."Multiple Entries";
        // Here i have to get S0001
    }
    else
    {
        echo $suppliername[$index]."+++"."Single Entry";
        // Here i have to get S0002
    }

}
```

how to pass `$index` to array value? I am trying to check value of the index is greater than or not in if condition. How to get this?

Comment: If you want to check supliers, why do you iterate over `$Product`?

Comment: Please could you provide the output of your print_rs. I believe the clue is there - there are no keys set.

Comment: print_r($suppliername); //Array ( [0] => S0001 [1] => S0001 [2] => S0002 )                 print_r($vals); //Array ( [S0001] => 2 [S0002] => 1 )  @Antony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code now it couldn't work since your `print_r($val)` result was :

```
Array
(
    [S0001] => 2
    [S0002] => 1
)
```

The key of your `$vals` are the result of your `$suppliername` array, so try like this maybe :

```
$Product = array("aaa","bbb","ccc");
$suppliername = array("S0001","S0002","S0001");
$vals = array_count_values($suppliername);
print_r($suppliername);
print_r($vals);

foreach($Product as $index => $value)
{
    if($vals[$suppliername[$index]]>1)
    {
        echo $suppliername[$index]."+++"."Multiple Entries";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $suppliername[$index]."+++"."Single Entry";
    }
}
```

The result :

```
S0001+++Multiple Entries
S0002+++Single Entry
S0001+++Multiple Entries
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes. @Mickael Leger Thanks you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help !

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure i understood well what you wanted, but here it does what you want as result :

```
<?php

$Product = array("aaa","bbb","ccc");
$suppliername = array("S0001","S0002","S0001");
$vals = array_count_values($suppliername);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($suppliername);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($vals);
echo "</pre>";

foreach($Product as $index => $value)
{
    if($index>1)
    {
        echo "<br />" . $suppliername[$index]."+++"."Multiple Entries";
        // Here i have to get S0001
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br />" . $suppliername[$index]."+++"."Single Entry";
        // Here i have to get S0002
    }

}
```

Comment: And what does this do? Checks index in `Product` and considers what?